# How to check if a number is rational or irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Today, I came across $\sqrt{11 + 6 \sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{11 - 6 \sqrt{2}} = 6$. Squaring it gives $36$, so this number is $6$. But let's say the *seemingly irrational number* given is more complicated and just squaring it does not help reveal its compact form. In such cases, how do I figure out if the number is rational or irrational?

Comment: In the same way, but involving more operations. If the situation does not resolve itself then you might suspect it is irrational. Then you would try to show that I guess.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here...in general, it can be very difficult to determine if a number is rational or not.

Comment: For example, nobody has proved yet that $\pi+e$ is irrational or rational.

Comment: For example, roots of polynomials with leading coefficient 1 and integer coefficients are integer or irrational, and we can easily find the integer ones.

Comment: @lulu It can be very difficult if the number is not known to be algebraic.  For an algebraic number, if you can find a polynomial over the rationals it is a root of, you can easily check whether the polynomial has rational roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{11-6\sqrt{2}} = 3-\sqrt{2},$$
$$\sqrt{11+6\sqrt{2}} = 3+\sqrt{2}.$$

Let us give a name to the double root, $\alpha = \sqrt{11-6\sqrt{2}}$.
This algebraic integer $\alpha$ satisfies the polynomial equation
$$
X^4-22X^2+49 = 0.
$$
This equation factors over ${\bf Q}$ as follows:
$$
X^4-22X^2+49 = (X^2+6X+7)(X^2-6X+7)
$$
thus explaining why we are in a degree two extension and not in a degree four extension of ${\bf Q}$. Note that standard CAS software such as [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) or maxima are pretty good at factoring polynomials over ${\bf Q}$ (disclaimer: I used sage).

Answer (score 2):

The comments already addressed the problem very well, here is a summary of all those ideas.

Note that if a complex number $z$ is a root of a **monic** non-zero polynomial
$$x^m+c_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots +c_1x +c_0$$ with integer coefficients $c_i$ for $i\in \{0,1,..,m-1\}$, then either $z$ is an integer or $z$ is irrational.

This theorem will be helpful if you want to show for example $\sqrt[d]{p}$ is irrational for prime number $p$ and $d\geq 2$.

Also, it is effective to show some seemingly more complicated numbers are irrational.

For example, to show $\alpha = \sqrt{11-6\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational, we will try to achieve the monic polynomial by rearranging and squaring:
\begin{align} \alpha = \sqrt{11-6\sqrt{2}} &\Leftrightarrow \alpha^2 = 11-6\sqrt{2}\\ &\Leftrightarrow (\alpha^2-11)^2= (-6\sqrt{2})^2\\
&\Leftrightarrow \alpha^4-22\alpha^2+49 = 0.
\end{align}

Hence, $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. By the theorem, to show $\alpha$ is irrational, it suffices to show $\alpha$ is not an integer, which is an easier task.

However, it might be hard to show a number is irrational if the number is not algebraic, (the above $\alpha$ is indeed an algebraic irrational number). For example, one way to show Euler's number $e$ (which is indeed transcendental or not algebraic) is irrational is based on the idea that the sum $e = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}$ converges rapidly. Intuitively, such cases are hard because they can be approximated extremely close by rational numbers.

Comment: Is the theorem used above the "Rational Root" theorem?

Comment: @NoChance Hi, I just searched this theorem for confirmation. Here is the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). It turned out that the theorem I use is a special case of the 'Rational Root' theorem, and it has the name 'Integral Root' theorem. It is a special case because the theorem I use assumes that the polynomial is monic.

Comment: Thank you much.